# The current user has insufficient permissions google api

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

I am trying to verify google in app subscription on my server end.

It seems to me that I need to create a service account for that.

I already had a "OldProject" Linked to my google play account, so Now, i created a service account under the project "OldProject" with "owner role" on the entire project.

But for some reason, when I use this service account and attempt to verify a purchaseToken, i get the error "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation".

I'm using the PHP validator from here https://github.com/aporat/store-receipt-validator

but i keep getting this error

```
    got error = { "error": { "errors": [ 
{ "domain": "androidpublisher", 
"reason": "permissionDenied",
 "message": "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation." } ], 
"code": 401, "message": "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation." } }
```

and Yes in API access i have granted this user permission as "Administrator" on all apps

and this is the PHP code

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$root = realpath(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
$library = "$root/library";

$path = array($library, get_include_path());
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $path));

require_once $root . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use ReceiptValidator\GooglePlay\Validator as PlayValidator;

// google authencation 
$applicationName = 'xxx-xxx';
$scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher'];
$configLocation = 'googleapi.json';

// receipt data
$packageName = 'com.xxxx.xxxx';
$productId = 'xxx';
$purchaseToken = 'xxxx';

$googleClient = new \Google_Client();
$googleClient->setScopes([\Google_Service_AndroidPublisher::ANDROIDPUBLISHER]);
$googleClient->setApplicationName($applicationName);
$googleClient->setAuthConfig($configLocation);

$googleAndroidPublisher = new \Google_Service_AndroidPublisher($googleClient);
$validator = new \ReceiptValidator\GooglePlay\Validator($googleAndroidPublisher);

try {
  $response = $validator->setPackageName($packageName)
      ->setProductId($productId)
      ->setPurchaseToken($purchaseToken)
      ->validateSubscription();
} catch (\Exception $e){
  var_dump($e->getMessage());
  // example message: Error calling GET ....: (404) Product not found for this application.
}
// success
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So had to wait over 24 hours (37 in my case) and it started working ... thanks google for wasting my time and not writing that we have to wait for this to update